# Find a repeater inside a unordered list inside a master page?

Tags: asp.net, master-pages

I have loaded my html template into my master page and then to bind category to database.
I have used this coding.

```
<ul class="categories">
            <li id="categoryItem">
                <h4>Categories</h4>
                <ul class="categories"  id="categorylist">            
                    <asp:Repeater ID="repCategories" runat="server">
                        <HeaderTemplate><ul></HeaderTemplate>
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <li>
                            <asp:HyperLink ID="hyperCategories" runat="server"><%#Eval("CategoryName")%></asp:HyperLink>
                            </li>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                        <FooterTemplate></ul></FooterTemplate>
                    </asp:Repeater>
                </ul>
            </li>
```

and try to bind this repeater to my database by doing coding on master.cs page.

```
 if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            DataSet ds = new ViewAction().GetAllProductCategoryData();
            repCategories.DataSource = ds;
            repCategories.DataBind();
        }
```

But it is showing the error that

`"The name repCategories does not exist in the current context"`

Why it is showing this error help me solve this. Please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason your code (as-written) isn't working, is because that Repeater is nested within 2 other server controls:

- `<li runat="server">` and
- `<ul class="categories" runat="server" id="categorylist">`.

This means the Repeater is in a different "naming container" than your top-level elements, and isn't directly accessible from you masterpage's codebehind file.

To fix this, you need to either

1. Remove `runat="server"` from those controls (if you don't actually need to access them from the server side code).  This will allow your code to work the way it is now.  ***Or,***
2. Add an ID to the `<li>` element, and then use the `FindControl` method to access your nested Repeater.

Option two would look something like this (we'll assume you gave the `<li>` an ID of "categoryItem"):

```
if (!IsPostBack)
{
    // Get the Repeater from nested controls first
    Repeater repCategories = (Repeater)categoryItem.FindControl("categorylist").FindControl("repCategories");
    // Do the rest of your work
    DataSet ds = new ViewAction().GetAllProductCategoryData();
    repCategories.DataSource = ds;
    repCategories.DataBind();
}
```

You need to use that code to "get" the Repeater in any place where you need to access it in codebehind.

Comment: @VJain You haven't show your whole masterpage markup. Are there other `runat="server"` controls outside of what you've shown? Also, can you confirm that this C# code is in the masterpage.aspx.cs file? I want to make sure I read your question correctly.

Comment: no sir, Actually now it is showing that error for categoryItem

Comment: @VJain You shouldn't be running the code that has categoryItem if you removed the "`runat="server"` references. Your code from the question should work (as long as there are not more server controls you haven't shown).

Comment: sir the above is modified there is no more runat="Server"

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/35004/discussion-between-jadarnel27-and-vjain)

Comment: the name categoryItem does not exist in the current context

Comment: sir i am really confused